# Migrated question closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5627/liquid-only-crash-diet?noredirect=1)

> Liquid only crash diet [migrated]

was migrated to [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3162/liquid-only-crash-diet).

According to me, the question belongs here at skeptics, and unfortunately it was closed there by [Ivo Flipse](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/8/ivo-flipse). Is there any method in place to detect and sort out this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, moderators have a "migration console" that shows how many migrated questions where deleted on the new sites.

On the other hand, I don't see how that question was on-topic here...

What you are asking basically sums up as medical advice. "Is this thing good for me?"

This is not on topic for a number of reasons:

- it is not about a claim and you don't seem skeptical of a claim in particular
- the question is very specific, about a specific product. On the other hand, the producers of said product do not claim that you should use it exclusively as the sole ingredient in a diet.
- [the claim itself does not seem notable.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-notable-does-a-claim-have-to-be-for-questions-about-it-to-be-considered-on-to)
- ["is it good/bad" are not very good questions in any case.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/please-add-all-instances-of-good-for-and-bad-for-to-the-filter)